# How to call function on particular date and time in javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timer

I am creating a web application, in that I need to call one function automatically in a particular date and time.I tried in many ways but I can't complete that module.

For example:

```
function autoRefresh1() {
    var fullDate = new Date();
    var twoDigitMonth = ((fullDate.getMonth().length+1) === 1)? (fullDate.getMonth()+1) : '0' + (fullDate.getMonth()+1);           
    var annualyear=fullDate.getFullYear();
    var currentDate = fullDate.getDate() + "/" + twoDigitMonth + "/";
    var time = fullDate.getHours() + ":" + fullDate.getMinutes() + ":" + fullDate.getSeconds();            
    var timestamp=currentDate+""+annualyear+"-"+time;

    if(timestamp=="19/08/"+annualyear+"-14:52:50") {

    }
```

One student is studying first standard means next year by particular date and time, the standard will increase to second standard. I got the solution when the particular web page is open in that particular date and time. But I need to run the function without open the web page, but the application will be in started position only. What I want to do, to achieve this module. Whether I want to use listener class or help me to find out the solution.

I hope someone will help me to come out from that module.

Comment: "*I need to run the function without open the web page*" - then it must not run within the webpage. Are you sure (clientside) javascript is the right tool?

Comment: yeah also the application is always in started position only.